# Change width of seekbar in landscape mode programmatically

Tags: android, android-widget

I have a problem with a width of SeekBar. I am trying to set width programmatically ( width of screen - 20px  ) with code 
            SeekBar seek = (SeekBar) temp
                    .findViewById(R.id.seek);

```
        android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams param = seek
                .getLayoutParams();

        param.width = width;
        //seek.setMinimumWidth(width);
```

and it works in portrait mode, but when I rotate phone or emulator, width of seekbar doesn't change. What to change ?

Answer (score 2):

Did you considered that when you rotate the phone the onCreate it is called again. Does your code in in the onCreate method ?, you have to make sure that your code it is actually called.

Make sure that this code get called, and it will be ok. Also I guess that this is not the complete code that you paste here on the forum, cause I do not see the setparams here, you have to call setparams(param) , (but I guess you have this in your real project)

```
  android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams param = seek
                .getLayoutParams();
        param.width = width;
```

Comment: I think I don't need setLAyoutParams because I am getting params like seekBar.getLayoutParams , it is reference not copy of object. I put breakpoints in debug mode but it didn't pass through onCreate or onResume.

Comment: the your problem is elsewhere, not in setting the width. To set the width the onCreate must get called

Comment: see this http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onConfigurationChanged(android.content.res.Configuration) this method is called when you switch between the portrait and landscape